# How to add a column with most resent recurring observation within a group, but within a certain time period, in R

Tags: r

If I had:

```
person_ID     visit date       
1               2/25/2001           
1               2/27/2001           
1               4/2/2001            
2               3/18/2004           
3               9/22/2004             
3               10/27/2004          
3               5/15/2008
```

and I wanted another column to indicate the earliest recurring observation within 90 days, grouped by patient ID, with the desired output:

```
person_ID     visit date           date
1               2/25/2001         2/27/2001
1               2/27/2001         4/2/2001
1               4/2/2001            NA
2               3/18/2004           NA
3               9/22/2004         10/27/2004 
3               10/27/2004          NA
3               5/15/2008           NA
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the 'visit_date' to `Date` class, grouped by 'person_ID', create a binary column that returns 1 if the difference between the current and next visit_date is less than 90 or else 0, using this column, get the correponding next visit_date' where the value is 1

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(visit_date = mdy(visit_date)) %>%
   group_by(person_ID) %>% 
   mutate(i1 = replace_na(+(difftime(lead(visit_date), 
   visit_date, units = 'day') < 90), 0), 
   date = case_when(as.logical(i1)~ lead(visit_date)), i1 = NULL ) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  person_ID visit_date date      
#      <int> <date>     <date>    
#1         1 2001-02-25 2001-02-27
#2         1 2001-02-27 2001-04-02
#3         1 2001-04-02 NA        
#4         2 2004-03-18 NA        
#5         3 2004-09-22 2004-10-27
#6         3 2004-10-27 NA        
#7         3 2008-05-15 NA
```